# Selenium Error - The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 60 seconds after clicking install button

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

while creating my test using c# and selenium i ran into a issue i haven't chad before. the test basically opens the web site, logs in as admin, and within the admin page i than have to install a plugin for this site that allows warranties feature to be enabled on the website. everything so far works, but when the test clicks the install button, the page goes into a installing/loading type of screen and then after a min my test fails because of time limits.
this this the error:

> Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the
>   remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:59515/session/c098338553dd7e3941e7e6c800273df3/element/0.3693091767590764-2/click
>   timed out after 60 seconds.   ----> System.Net.WebException : The
>   operation has timed out.

now the test does installs the plugin as it supposed to but my test will still fail and i can not continue with the rest of the test because of this time out. I know it has to do with webdriver or remotedriver that has the default timer set to 60 seconds, but i just don't know how to go around and either extending that time limit or if there is another way to go about this?

Comment: How you are installing the plug-in, is there any element to click for this? And do you get any specific element once the installation is completed?

Comment: @supputuri there is a button to click which im using "_driver.FindElement(By.Name("install-plugin-link-Warranty.STORIS"));" . and the test when it runs, does click on that button and begins to install but the issue is it takes close to 3 minutes to intall the plugin  which by than the test fails because of remote webdriver has a set time of 60 secs before it fails the test and i just cant seem to figure out a way to change that.

Comment: If there is any specific element that will be displayed once the installation is completed, then you can write the code to wait for that element using `expected conditions` and provide 5 mins. So that the script will continue once the element is there. something like this `new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Xpath(postInstallationElementXpathGoesHere))));`

Comment: Thank you Im going to run the program with what you suggested, but i noticed that when implementing, visual studios made the suggestion to include [Obsolete] above the test case.

Comment: just tried that way and still run into the same issue, "WebDriver server for URL"" timed out after 60 seconds". even with the next line implementing the logout function call which has the WebDriverWait line of code that was suggested.

Comment: Can you try one more option, click the button using javascript and then hard code wait for 3 mintures (i know we should not use hard coded wait) so that we get to know if `install` button click causing any issue.